# Alamofire downloading multiple images using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I currently have a an array of strings that contain about three thousand urls to download images. I have set up the following function to the pass the array of urls into:

```
   func downloadAllImages(urlArray:[String])->Void{
    var urlArray = urlArray
    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
    var TotalProducts = urlArray.count
    for i in 0 ..< urlArray.count  {
        Alamofire.download(
            urlArray[i],
            method: .get,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                self.IndividualImage.text="\(progress.fractionCompleted*100)%"

            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                TotalProducts-=1
                self.DownloadLabel.text="Images left to download: \(TotalProducts)"
                print("\(DefaultDownloadResponse.error)")
                print("\(DefaultDownloadResponse.response)")
            })
    }
}
```

This works fine except it tends to cut out after downloading between 800-900 images and just stops. It outputs no errors. As I'm looping through every url and creating a task I imagine there are only so many concurrent tasks I can have at once. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** 
 
I have gone through the output responses and found many are timing out:

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800145b840 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=www.MYURL.com/image1.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=www.MYURL.com/image1.jpg, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
```

So this is obvious as the for loop is sending everything to a task at once virtually and then it can only process so many at once. So the answer is to send them in batches. But how would I send a batch of 50 and then wait till every task has completed and then send another wave?

Comment: How big is the size of images? There is a limit of 2GB for document directory.

Comment: Each image is around 500kb. So 3000x500kb is 1.5GB so it should be fine.

Comment: You can use DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async function to run that task in background.

Comment: I've tried wrapping the function in a dispatchQueue and it still cuts out after 800-900 images

Comment: whoever will be trying to achieve working code like this, migh consider using DispatchGroup.notify, which can notify you after your batch is complete, and only after that, start downloading another